# Microstation VBA - Relative file path to run .bat script

Tags: excel, vba7, microstation

Im using VBA for Microstation Connect.  I added the excel tag because the site didnt recognize Microstation as a platform application.

Im trying to run a separate bat script in a specific location with a relative file path.

Ive been using this successfully as an absolute path but I need to get there with a relative path as simply as possible.

```
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell("D:\~Temp\Test project 2\Tscan\Settings\MS Scripts and Macros\enter.bat", 6)
```

Im trying to modify it to use a relative file path like this, which has not been working:

```
Dim RetVal
RetVal = Shell(ActiveDesignFile.Path & "..\" & "\Settings\MS Scripts and Macros\enter.bat", 6)
```

I suspect I should not be using the quotes to delineate ".." but when I remove them I get the error "Expected: identifier or bracketed expression.

Any suggestions?